# How to get jQuery FancyTree to call my method for data?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, fancytree

In my TestPage.aspx file I've got the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Create the tree inside the <div id="tree"> element.
        $("#tree").fancytree({
            source: { url: "/GetTreeData", cache: false },
            checkbox: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm a bit of a newby to working with jQuery controls and making ajax calls but I assumed this would call my method in the code behind defined as:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod( UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, XmlSerializeString = false )]
public static object GetTreeData()
{
    List<TreeNode> nodes = new List<TreeNode>()
    {
        new TreeNode()
        {
            key = "1",
            title = "Node1"
        },

        new TreeNode()
        {
            key = "2",
            title = "Node2",
            children = new List<TreeNode>() { new TreeNode() { key = "2.1", title = "Node 2.1" } }
        }
    };

    return nodes;
}
```

It never calls the method though, which I know because I put a breakpoint at the start of it and it never gets hit (and the tree just displays a loading picture). Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
source: { url: "/GetTreeData", cache: false }
```

should be replaced by:

```
source: { url: "/TestPage.aspx/GetTreeData", cache: false }
```

Comment: Yep, too bad you weren't here to answer a couple weeks ago before I figured it out on my own. Ah well, thanks anyway :)